# How can I address this issue and ensure that the IDs match correctly during client-side hydration?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt3

I'm encountering a hydration attribute mismatch in my Nuxt.js application related to a DisclosureButton with the ID 'nav-id'. The error message indicates that the element is rendered on the server with the ID 'headlessui-disclosure-button-22', but on the client, it's expected to have the ID 'headlessui-disclosure-button-1'. The mismatch is check-only, and the DOM won't be rectified in production due to performance overhead

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8SxN.png)

`your text`
Check Server-Side Rendering (SSR) Implementation:
Ensure that your Nuxt.js project is correctly configured for SSR. Make sure your components are handling SSR appropriately, especially if they involve dynamic content or state.

Use data() Instead of ref() for Server-Rendered Data:
Instead of using the Composition API's ref(), consider using the data() function for server-rendered data. This ensures that the data is initialized on the server and avoids hydration mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

In Nuxt.js, you can use the client-only component to conditionally render content only on the client side. Here's how you can use it in your menu to address the hydration issue:

```
<client-only>
    <DisclosureButton
      id="nav-id"
      class="relative inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500"
    >
      <span class="absolute -inset-0.5" />
      <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        fill="none"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        stroke-width="1.5"
        stroke="currentColor"
        class="w-6 h-6"
        v-if="!open"
      >
        <path
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
          d="M3.75 5.25h16.5m-16.5 4.5h16.5m-16.5 4.5h16.5m-16.5 4.5h16.5"
        />
      </svg>
    </DisclosureButton>
  </client-only>
```